# In Swift is it possible to create implicit conversions for your class types?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

One of the things I love about C# is you can define implicit converters for your classes.  For instance, I created a `VectorGeometryBuilder` class that has methods like `MoveForwardByX`, `TurnByYDegrees`, `LineToPoint`, etc. It then defines an implicit conversion to a `Geometry` class.  This allows me to use my nifty builder to create my geometry, then just pass the whole object along as-is to any function expecting a `Geometry`, even though `VectorGeometryBuilder` itself is *not* a subclass of `Geometry.` Instead it exposes a `Geometry` object as a property, which the implicit converter grabs and returns.

What I'm wondering is if Swift has something similar.

Consider this made-up scenario...

```swift
class FauxInt {

    init(_ initialValue: Int) {
        value = initialValue
    }
    var value:Int
}

let fauxInt = FauxInt(14)

// These are the kind of things I'm trying to be able to do...

let realInt:Int = fauxInt

someFuncTakingAnInt(someInt: fauxInt)
```

Again, the conversion to `Int` should be implicit meaning anywhere that's expecting an `Int`, I can use or pass a `FauxInt` instead.

Is there any way to make the above possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift doesn't support implicit conversion - the closest equivalent is done through extra constructors. So to convert a Double to an Int:

```
let i: Int = Int(myDouble)
```

In your case, you could define an extension to Int to create a new init that takes fauxInit as a parameter:

```
extension Int {
    init(_ myFaux: FauxInt) {
        self = myFaux.value
    }
}

let fauxInt = FauxInt(14)
let realInt = Int(fauxInt)
```

Comment: Yeah, not quite the same. And while I appreciate what can be done here, if the object you're "converting" with a new initializer exposes an int property already, most likely instead of this... someFuncTakingInt(Int(fauxInt))... i'd probably just write this anyway... someFuncTakingInt(fauxInt.value).  In other words, without the capability of implicit conversion, this really doesn't add that much, at least in this case. Still, voting you up because in other cases, this would be a very helpful tip and does follow Swift standards.